# Should I run sudo mysql_secure_installation after installing mysql?

Tags: server, mysql

I just installed `mysql`. I need to know should I run this command:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

and after installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It would be better if you run command as it provides many security options like:

- You can set a password for root accounts.
- You can remove root accounts that are accessible from outside the
  local host.
- You can remove anonymous-user accounts.
- You can remove the test database, which by default can be accessed by
  anonymous users

if you want to set.